# Android PictureView keeps crashing

Tags: java, android, crash, imageview

I've recently added a pictureView to my app, and for some reason, whatever I do, it crashes.

It crashes when I add picture using both xml and adding it programmatically.
Source is below:

XML

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>
```

.Java file:

```
package tk.yteditors.london2013;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams;

public class PictActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_pict);
    Drawable drawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.map);
    ImageView imageview = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams vp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    imageview.setLayoutParams(vp);
    imageview.setImageDrawable(drawable);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

Edit: also the case on BlueStacks app player, so on all devices i suppose.

Comment: The guess is where you set the layout params

Comment: @Arju I dont have a logcat because my adb drivers don't want to install. + I have set layout parameters in the code: both WRAP_CONTENT

Comment: What you meant by , you dont have a logcat? Are you not using eclipse?

Comment: I am using eclipse but... logcat is that you hook up your phone and see a nice log right? In that case: the ADB drivers aint installing

Comment: Maybe the fact that my picture is 5894X4346 pixels is making this not work?

Comment: Thats not logcat, Just goto Window -> show view -> logcat, Try that you will get logcat there for emulator also ok. Any crash will be reported there

Comment: I have found the solution:
My picture was way too big.
I downsized it and that fixed it.